# Git synchronize between two remotes

Tags: git

I'm working with an infrastructure as followed:

[image: Infrastructure]

My laptop, Workstation B and server B are all at my job. Now to allow for working from home, I want to be able to work on workstation A.

My laptop is the only device that could connect to both servers simultaniously, as I've got a VPN set up at home.

In the current project we're working in one repository with a whole bunch of submodules.

My question is, how can I use my laptop to synchronize the data between server A and B, so that I can work on Workstation A whenever I want to?

As I mostly work on Workstation B, and not my laptop, I tend to forget to pull changes to my laptop. Therefore I was thinking if it would be possible to have my laptop have two remotes, server A and B, and on my workstation use my laptop as a remote. However, as my laptop requires a working copy and not a bare repository, git complains that the given location is not a working copy.

Comment: As I understand it, you can fetch updates along any line in the graph, so what's the problem?

Comment: @meagar The problem is that when I'm at home, the lines between my laptop and Workstation B, and the line between my laptop and Server B are both unavailable. Being human, I forget (or, being programmer, I'm too lazy) to pull to my laptop and then push to Server A every time I commit something.

Comment: Then... you're screwed. You cannot use Git to transfer data in the absence of a network connection. Wait until you're back at the office and push/pull your changes. I'm not really clear what you're after, some kind of automatic pushing/pulling script that automatically synchronizes all machines each time a commit is made? Just put your working directory inside Dropbox if you really can't remember to manually push/pull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every copy of a git repository is a full clone and can have multiple remotes. Usually you would just clone out (personal repo, not a bare one) from the server onto your desired machine and then use pushing and pulling to update the branches on each server.

So to get code from workstation B onto workstation A

- On Workstation B make a change on your branch, say master, commit it
  and push it to remote Server B
- On laptop clone the repo from server B (or add it as a remote to an
  existing one) and then checkout master and pull from the remote for
  server B. Master on the laptop is now the same as server B and
  Workstation B
- On laptop add server A as a remote and push to the remote for server
  A. Now server A has the same master branch pointer too
- On workstation A clone from Server A.

Now all places have a master branch pointing to the same commit. You can work backwards in the same manner, or sync up multiple branches if you so wish. The key being to have 2 remotes on laptop and push and pull to both of them.

Comment: Would it, instead of having Server B as remote on workstation B, be possible to have my laptop as remote for Workstation B?

Comment: A git remote can simply a folder (as well as the usual git protocol or http protocol server remotes) so as long as the machines have file access to each other they can consider each other as remotes.