# Merging all changes from a GitHub repository to a non-GitHub repository, similar to fork functionality

Tags: git

I have a repository based on "https://github.com/MicrochipTech/amazon-freertos.git", I have pushed this to my own repository, which is not in Github so I believe fork is not possible. In my newly created copy I have added my application files as well as some changes to the amazon source files. This is committed and pushed to my private repository.

When the amazon repository eventually changes, is there some way that I can merge those changes into my repository, yet keeping the changes i have made to the previous version of that repository? Note that I will have modified some of the files that are part of the amazon repository so I cannot simply have it as a submodule.

Edit:
As suggested I have:

```
git clone -b mchpdev_20210700 --origin microchip --origin microchip https://github.com/MicrochipTech/amazon-freertos.git
cd amazon-freertos
git remote add origin https://git-codecommit.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/my-amazon-freertos
H:\dev\test\amazon-freertos>git remote -v
microchip       https://github.com/MicrochipTech/amazon-freertos.git (fetch)
microchip       https://github.com/MicrochipTech/amazon-freertos.git (push)
origin  https://git-codecommit.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/my-amazon-freertos (fetch)
origin  https://git-codecommit.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/my-amazon-freertos (push)

H:\dev\test\amazon-freertos>git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://git-codecommit.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/my-amazon-freertos
  Push  URL: https://git-codecommit.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/my-amazon-freertos
  HEAD branch: (unknown)

H:\dev\test\amazon-freertos>git push
Username for 'https://github.com':

H:\dev\test\amazon-freertos> git push origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git-codecommit.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/my-amazon-freertos'
```

Looks like the push is going to Github rather than my repository now, I need to repoint it to my repo somehow. If I specify origin master I get the above error message

Edit:
Following the commands above and committing with `git push origin HEAD:master`, I successfully uploaded the remote microchip repo as well as my own files to my own private repo and I am also able to pull changes from microchip repo, but pending verification on how it will work once there are updates there.

Comment: Did you clone the repository originally with git or did you copy and paste the files?

Comment: @DMalan will I cloned it, cleaned out the git files and init as a new git. But at this stage I can redo it in another way if needed, but I need a workable solution going forward.

Comment: Git can work with multiple remote repositories. Just pull from the one and push to the other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git synchronize between two remotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593352/git-synchronize-between-two-remotes)

Comment: Take a look at the value of `branch.master.remote` and `branch.master.merge` and read `git-config`'s manual.  Also check out the `--set-upstream` option of `git push`.

Comment: Thanks, not sure what this issue was but I resolved it with this "git push origin HEAD:master". Can see my added files as well as the remote repository is now in my repo, just need to test a bit to ensure i can pull changes from the Github repo but hopefully it will work well.

Comment: @Joe, may be similar use case but it doesn't really explain how, but thanks for pointing it out. I think we have found the solution here now so all good.

Comment: Note that if you don't use `-o` or `--origin`, the default name is `origin`. So `--origin origin` would do the same thing. You're using `--origin microchip` so you've changed the name `origin` to `microchip`. (Why are you using `--origin` at all, and especially, why did you use it *twice?)*

Comment: @torek, thanks for the explanation, I followed the steps in the answer below, maybe there is a typo there, not sure.

Comment: You can use `-o` or `--origin` if you like, it's just that I've never seen anyone actually *do* it. The weird thing is that you used it twice. That's not in D Malan's answer, that's in your original (or edited? ah, edited) problem statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple [git remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) and pull in changes from either of them.

You can clone the original repository with a custom remote name, e.g.:

```
git clone --origin microsoft git@github.com:MicrochipTech/amazon-freertos.git
```

Then add your own remote:

```
git remote add origin git@<your-repository>.git
```

After making custom commits and your repository, you can pull in the latest changes from the original repository by specifying the remote after `git pull`:

```
git pull microsoft master # Pull from original repository
```

Git will merge the original repository's changes into yours. You will be prompted to fix merge conflicts if there are any.

Comment: This looks good, but I'm not quite able to get it right. Even I do "git remote add origin https://git-codecommit.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/my-amazon-freertos" and I can see it looks good ">git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://git-codecommit.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/my-amazon-freertos
  Push  URL: https://git-codecommit.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/my-amazon-freertos
  HEAD branch: (unknown)".
But push still goes to github for some reason "H:\dev\test\amazon-freertos>git push
Username for 'https://github.com':"

Comment: Thanks, took me awhile to figure out but after adding "git push origin HEAD:master" it appears to work, and I can pull from remote repo, but at this time there are no changes so need to wait till theres an update to confirm, but based on output looks like its all working. Many thanks for all the help here, very much appreciated!